# Python - Flask: How do i assign variables before rendering?

Tags: python, variables, flask, template-engine

I've been searching for the way to assign variables before rendering but didn't find anything.

In PHP i can do this way in any function separately before rendering template, all i needed is `$tpl` object:

```
$tpl->assign('a', $a);
$tpl->output(...);
```

So it's quite difficult to handle the process like return output out of `@app.route` or assign variable to template with Flask

For example, i want to handle message report (return or assign variable) if user enabled javascript or not, if user do ajax request, it returns json string, and if itsn't, assign variable to the template.

Here is my code

```
@admin.route('/login')
def login():
    ...
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return helper.msg_report(...)

    return render_template('login.pug', **locals())

def msg_report(ajax, type, msg):
    if not ajax:
        # need to assign msg variable to template here
    else:
        res = dict()
        res['error'] = dict()
        res['error']['message'] = mark_msg('error', msg)
        return json.dumps(res)
```

Comment: You can use branching in your template code. I don't see a good reason for assigning values ahead.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule The good reason is you can seprate the code, in this case, a reusable code to handle error message. With PHP, i only need few line of code, with Python + Flask, i have no clue how do i do it, it also breaks the object oriented design - there's no template object! I've tested many form view with Flask like Flask-Admin, Wtforms ... none of them have done a single job with ajax.

Comment: Jinja is robust. You can selectively `include` *(there is an include directive for that)* reusable templates for errors. There is a template object, it's just abstracted away since you really don't need to deal with it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule So how do i access to that template object? I know how template engine works, but let's try to solve my case, ajax form validation it has to return result from code manually, since i see no ajax things supported by `flask-*`

Comment: What kind of result?

Comment: If you'll be returning a json string. You can use `jsonify` from flask. I don't think you really need access to the template object. However, you can register a signal handler that is called before the template is rendered.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule My question is clear, please read my code. i want to return json string if there ajax=1, or assign message variable to the template if ajax=0 to output error to user

Comment: Couldn't solve the trouble

Answer (score 0):

The variables you assign to template are `**locals()` in your example.

For example, suppose there is a variable named `text` in your template. You can assign it by `return render_template('login.pug', text="what you want")`.

So you just need to return a dictionary such as `result = msg_report(ajax, type, msg)`, and then `return render_template('login.pug', **result)`.

Comment: I know, but it still need to define `result` variable inside, mean writing more code, any way auto generate variable or assign them to template object?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a response right there in `msg_report`. 
When `form.validate_on_submit` is truthy, updating the template context alone will return `None`. i.e.
No response will be returned to client.

```
from flask import jsonify, render_template

...

def msg_report(ajax, type, msg, **ctx): # pass variables needed by template here
    if not ajax:
        # update ctx before passing here
        ctx.update({'error': msg})

        return render_template('login.pug', **ctx)

    rv = {
        'error': {
            'message':  mark_msg('error', msg)
        }
    }

    return jsonify(rv)
```

If you will still like to go ahead to update template context, you can use:

```
from flask import current_app as app

ctx = {
    'error': msg
}

app.update_template_context(ctx)
```

Comment: I got the error `NameError: name 'render_template' is not defined` what is ctx i have to pass by? `msg_report` is inside other file (helper.py)

Comment: I think that should be `locals()`. you pass it where `helper.msg_report` is called

Comment: `**local()` is all the local variables inside `login()`, all of them will be assigned to template object. About your code, `render_template` will never work because it's out of `@app.route('/')`?

Comment: How do you mean `render_template` will not work? Did you import  the `render_template` function from `flask` before using it in `helpers.msg_report`?

Comment: Sorry, i've imported `render_template`, however still couldn't make it work, because the template need `form = LoginForm()` i declared in routing file to work, and i don't think this is good practice, `render_template` should never left the routing file

Comment: "`render_template` should never leave the routing file." Do you mean the view function? This not being good practice is news to me. If template needs form, then make sure form is passed to `helpers.msg_report`. As it stands, you can do the logic in `helpers.msg_report` directly in your view function. As I said earlier, it's not obvious to me why all that logic was moved to `helpers.msg_report`. If you're not re-using it now, then move it back and refactor later. Some IDEs even help you with refactoring into a function.